# Extra inter-line spacing in a tabular environment (Version 2)

Tags: tables, spacing

I have a table that is typeset using a tabular environment. (I want to keep it in a tabular environment.) The inter-line spacing in each table is determined by `\\[1.2\normalbaselineskip]`.  What spacing should I use between the text preceding the `tabular` environment and the `tabular` environment?  What would the analog to `\\[1.2baselineskip]` be in `text` mode?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}

\begin{document}

\noindent {\textbf{Example}} \vskip1.25mm
The following functions are increasing on the interval $[0, \, \infty)$. \\
\hspace*{3em}
\begin{tabular}{r @{\ }l}
\textbf{i.)}    &       $\sqrt[\uproot{1} \leftroot{-1} 3]{x^{3} + 2x^{2} + 3x - 7}$ \\[1.2\normalbaselineskip]
\textbf{ii.)}   &       $x^{3} + 2x^{2} + 3x - 7$ \\[1.2\normalbaselineskip]
\textbf{iii.)}  &       $x^{2} + \sqrt{x}$ \\[1.2\normalbaselineskip]
\textbf{iv.)}   &       $\displaystyle{\frac{-1}{x^{2} + 1}}$
\end{tabular}
\vskip0.25in


\noindent {\textbf{Example}} \vskip1.25mm
Solve the following equations. \\
\hspace*{3em} 
\begin{tabular}{r @{\ }l}
\textbf{i.)}    &   $\displaystyle{\frac{3}{50} \, x + \frac{3}{20} \, \Bigl(10 - x\Bigr) = \frac{3}{4} \, x}$ \\[1.2\normalbaselineskip]
\textbf{ii.)}   &   $\displaystyle{\left(2\sin{x} - \sqrt{3}\right) = 0}$ \\[1.2\normalbaselineskip]
\textbf{iii.)}  &   $2\tan\theta\sin\theta + \sqrt{3}\tan\theta = 2\sqrt{3}\sin\theta + 3$ \\[1.2\normalbaselineskip]
\textbf{iv.)}   &   $\displaystyle{\frac{x}{4} = 2^{\log_{x}8}}$
\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

Comment: most obvious analogue is `\\[1.2baselineskip] `  why the horrible  `\noindent {\textbf{Example}} \vskip1.25mm` mix of tex primitives and latex font commands instead of `\section*{example}`  ? You should never need to have explicit spaces like 1.2mm _in the document_ they should be part of the definition of the relevant heading.

Comment: also within the table you should not have `\\[1.2\normalbaselineskip]` on every row, the option should be for special rows which need an extra gap for some reason. `\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}`  will make the table use  20% bigger row spacing with a normal `\\ ` at the ends of rows.

Answer (score 3):

I would do something like this

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}

\usepackage{enumitem}


\begin{document}

\section*{Example}
The following functions are increasing on the interval $[0, \, \infty)$.
\begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\roman{enumi}.)},itemsep=17pt,topsep=10pt]
\item  $\displaystyle \sqrt[\uproot{1} \leftroot{-1} 3]{x^{3} + 2x^{2} + 3x - 7}$
\item  $\displaystyle x^{3} + 2x^{2} + 3x - 7$
\item  $\displaystyle x^{2} + \sqrt{x}$
\item  $\displaystyle \frac{-1}{x^{2} + 1}$
\end{enumerate}



\section*{Example}
Solve the following equations.
\begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\roman{enumi}.)},itemsep=17pt,topsep=10pt]
\item $\displaystyle \frac{3}{50} \, x + \frac{3}{20} \, \Bigl(10 - x\Bigr) = \frac{3}{4} \, x$
\item $\displaystyle (2\sin{x} - \sqrt{3}) = 0$
\item  $\displaystyle 2\tan\theta\sin\theta + \sqrt{3}\tan\theta = 2\sqrt{3}\sin\theta + 3$ 
\item  $\displaystyle \frac{x}{4} = 2^{\log_{x}8}$
\end{enumerate}


\end{document}
```

Note this uses structural elements like sections and lists rather than font changes and spacing. the heading here is centred small caps as that is the `amsart` style, if you used `article` it would be bold and flush left.

Note that `\displaystyle` does not take a  `{...}` argument, and if you use it you should use it in all cases, otherwise positioning of subscripts etc will be inconsistent.

Comment: I agree that I am using a hodgepodge of basic `TeX` commands and this is inconsistent with the code of others.  Please post a link to your manual for this package.  Does `topsep=10pt` separate the baseline of the text preceding the `enumerate` environment with the top of the box containing the first item of the `enumerate` environment.  Is `10pt` "artistic license"?